# Custom button doesn't display its drawables

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom button `button.xml`. Its default (unpressed) drawable is `button_unclicked.xml` and the `button_clicked.xml` is called when the button is clicked. The problem is the button doesn't display its clicked and unclicked drawables, but only a text inside the button (there is no borders).

I'm setting my custom button as a background:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/apply"
    android:id="@+id/button_apply"
    android:onClick="Apply"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/button" />
```

button_clicked:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#FFE75C" />
</shape>
```

button_unclicked:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:angle="270" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>

</selector>
```

button.xml:

```
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_clicked">
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_unclicked">
</item>
```

output (there should be borders but there aren't): 
[image]

Comment: How are you using your button? Please post the actual code for what's happening, and what the output looks like.

Comment: Why is there a `</selector>` tag in button_unclicked.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this 
drawable/selector.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_enabled="false" >
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" >
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#FFE75C" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape
                android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
                      android:angle="270" />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom Button"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_light" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_light" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_focused_holo_light" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_light" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_focused_holo_light" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_disabled_holo_light"/>

</selector>
```

You don't have to put all of the `<item>` tags.